# c# draw simple workflow diagram and mark current status

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# Winform project and I need to create a very simple linear workflow just to show visually what is the current status of the record.

Here is a sample image of what I want to do:

[image]

I will have to be able to draw the border on the item that is the actual status.

Any advice?

Comment: use panel with same padding  from all the sides and on the basis of status mark the specific panel background as red

Comment: @VAAA - Did my example give you a good idea, or does it need elaboration with screenshots and such?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to actually draw on it, you can do as rashfmnb suggested. Here is an example.

The setup:

- Form = MainForm
- Panel = pnlOuter [Padding = 5]
- Panel = pnlInner [Parent = pnlOuter, done by placing it inside the other one; Dock = Fill]
- Button = ToggleColor (to trigger the click event handler below)

The code:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
  bool isOn = false;
  public MainForm()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     pnlInner.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
     pnlOuter.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
  }

  private void ToggleColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (isOn)
     {
        pnlOuter.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
        isOn = false;
     }
     else
     {
        pnlOuter.BackColor = Color.Red;
        isOn = true;
     }
  }
}
```

This simple example just toggles the background of the outer panel. In your case, you would use different values to check what should be set and so forth.

Comment: If you want to go all-out, you can build your component (panels, label, etc) and wrap it up as a control. That way you can just drop one in and set its properties instead of having to create 4 or more instances of all of those nested controls such.